# Serialize Form data (including array) to JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, forms, serialization, stringify

So I basically have a modal to add an object, that I want to serialize to JSON Object. To serialize each input will have a name and value of course.

The thing is one of those inputs have a value which is an array (list of ids). This input is actually hidden and I have set it my self.

Following are the steps I followed

1. Set the hidden input values

   ```
   $('input[name="students"]').val(JSON.stringify(idsArray));
   ```
2. Serialize the form into object

   ```
   action_object = $('.actionForm').serializeObject();
   ```

   Source for SerialzeObject function
   [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)
3. Convert to JSON object

   ```
   action_JSON = JSON.stringify(action_object);
   ```
4. Result is as following

   ```
   {"Title":"","students":"[\"2015022\",\"2015027\",\"2015032\"]","ActionType":"3","Description":"yjtkt","Date":"2015-11-17"}
   ```

Now the object seems ok.

However check for the students array. Is that normal and if not how that can be fixed ?

Comment: "_Is that normal_": Yes. It's the string representation of a string representation of an array containing strings (`idsArray`)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks that helps